# how to undo query in phpmyadmin?

Tags: phpmyadmin, rollback

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to undo a query execution in phpmyadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836455/how-to-undo-a-query-execution-in-phpmyadmin)

I have a stupid mistake. It cause by I'm very sleepy.

Actually i want to update some date from `B table`, but I mistype for that query. I type `A table` so all of data inside `A table` is changed. I'm using `Phpmyadmin`.

I'm very panic for now. Could anyone give me some suggestion for this case?

---

the data are not deleted but the date is changed.

Comment: I take it you don't have backups.

Comment: I have some backup just for May,June,and July.but for August until September I haven't.

Comment: @Pekka: I think that Q not help me.

Comment: @nunu that's because there is no way to undo a query if you're not working with transactions. Sorry.

Comment: @Pekka: the answer below said that I can use rollback.but this transaction is already done.

Comment: @nunu yeah. I don't think there is a way to undo that action then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4591/discussion-between-nunu-and-pekka)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to undo a query. If the query was something like `UPDATE a SET x = x + 1`, you could reverse it with `UPDATE a SET x = x - 1`, but other than that, you cannot revert queries. The best thing you can do is restoring a backup you've made before.

Comment: I have each month back up how to replace that data? because I set my table cant duplicate.

Comment: @nunu: you can restore the subject table from your backup to a second database/table and try to recover data in that way. I don't know enough about your situation to guide you further, sorry.