# Does phpMyAdmin have an equivalent of CTRL + Z

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I just overwrote a field for all rows of  a database.  I have no back up file.  Is there a field in phpMyAdmin that would let me undo this?

Comment: once you overwrite it, its pretty much done

Comment: So you're creating backups **right now**, right?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you a bit. Hope everything will work out in some way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4836463/1693248